# PCI e 3.0 Graphics cards and PCI e 2.0 Motherboards

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

Can a PCI-e 3.0 card (mid-budget) exceed the bandwidth of a PCI-e 2.0 of a motherboard?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
Now I'm sure it won't decrease lifespan of mainboard (such as auto - increased clock frequency) other than its available bandwidth for other slots, thanks to the answerer and some research over internet. It feels like ignorance to ask this question when reading now.

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed on superuser. I'd suggest rewording your question.

Comment: Okay, edited it to catch the main idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any PCIe version 3 card should work in any PCIe version 2.0 slot, but at PCIe v2 speeds.

Since it will work at v2 speed it can not exceed v2 speed.