# Motherboard 2.0 x16 will accept graphics card PCI-E 3.0 x16?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I am considering buying the motherboard listed below. The specs say it has a PCI-E 2.0 x16 slot. There are PCI-E 2.0 x16 video cards. But there are 3.0 x16 graphics cards available but there don't seem to be motherboards that list 3.0 x16 in their specs.

What in the specs of a motherboard would indicate that a video card 3.0 x16 would be compatible? Maybe the specs of the motherboard should in fact list 3.0 x16 if the slot is available, I'm just not finding them?

GIGABYTE GA-970A-D3 AM3+ AMD 970 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard

Thanks,
Charlie

Comment: possible duplicate of [A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot](http://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot) also see [PCI e 3.0 Graphics cards and PCI e 2.0 Motherboards](http://superuser.com/questions/478377/pci-e-3-0-graphics-cards-and-pci-e-2-0-motherboards?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will only find PCIe 3.0x16 listed on Intel based motherboards of the newer variety.

Here is a sample Intel board from the same manufacturer:

[Gigabyte board with PCIe 3.0x16 Model GA-Z77X-UD3H](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128544)

Partial spec list up to the PCIe expansion slots:

> GIGABYTE Model GA-Z77X-UD3H
>
> Supported CPU
>   CPU Socket TypeLGA 1155CPU TypeCore i7 / i5 / i3 (LGA1155)
>
> Chipsets
>   North BridgeIntel Z77
>
> Number of Memory Slots4×240pin Memory StandardDDR3 2666(OC)/1600/1333/1066Maximum Memory Supported32GBChannel SupportedDual Channel
>
> Expansion Slots
>
> **PCI Express 3.0 x16  =2 (x16, x8)**
>
> **PCI Express 2.0 x16 = 1 @x4**
>
> **PCI Express x1 = 3**

PCIe 3.0 are backward compatible to PCIe 2.0x16

Comment: Thanks much. Yes, my search was limited to AMD boards.